# JavaScript: how to pass date values to function

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I came across the following function which is used to calculate the difference between two dates in business days, i.e. by eliminating standard weekends / Saturdays and Sunday (source: http://partialclass.blogspot.ie/2011/07/calculating-working-days-between-two.html):

```
function workingDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) 
{
    if (endDate < startDate)        
        return 0;   

    var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; 

    startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);  
    endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);  

    var diff = endDate - startDate;  
    var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);        
    var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);    
    var days = days - (weeks * 2);    
    var startDay = startDate.getDay();    
    var endDay = endDate.getDay();        

    if (startDay - endDay > 1)                 
    days = days - 2;              

    if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)       
    days = days - 1                  

    if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)        
    days = days - 1          

    return days;
    alert(days);
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can pass two dates to call this function ?
My dates would be variables in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim

Comment: I don't understand the questions. Why don't you simply invoke the function passing those date variables?

Comment: So the question really is "how do I invoke a javascript function?" - which has been [addressed plenty of times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+do+I+invoke+javascript). Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

say

```
var startDate = "2014-05-22";
var endDate   = "2014-06-22";
```

you can call the function like this

```
workingDaysBetweenDates(new Date(startDate),new Date(endDate));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Sorry, I tried this but it returns NaN instead of a number - does the function work for you ?

Comment: can you paste the values of startDate and endDate which you are passing to the function?

Comment: exactly the same as above - my problem is that I am trying to use the result for anything else, e.g. to alert it or to add it to a variable but when I refer to the variable "days" here it alerts NaN and returns nothing

Comment: interesting. when i call the function with those values , im getting the value 22

Comment: did you make any changes to the way the function is written above or use it the same way ? in my case it seems that the variable days is always empty or declined as undefined.

Comment: could you paste the full code of what you are doing? that way we can figure it out where the mistake is happening

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47419/discussion-between-user2571510-and-anurupr)

Answer (score 0):

```
let startDate = new Date("2014-05-22") ;
let endDate   = new Date("2014-06-22") ;

displayDate(startDate,endDate){
    // Your content
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you read the five year old question carefully? It is asking how to call the function in the question, not how to call `displayDate`. It is more a question about how to work with that particular function that they found given the format that their data is already in.